# Exception return None

Tags: python, exception

I want to catch an error when calling a function. For example, the Internet is gone.
I do this:

```
    def get_position(self) -> position.Position:
       result = position.Position()
       try:
           return result.json_parse(self.client.futures_position_information(symbol=SYMBOl))
       except Exceptione:
           print(f'err: GET_POSITION {e}')
           time.sleep(5)
           self.get_position()
```

After the advent of the Internet. The function returns None. I understand that this is not correct. How to do it right?

Comment: After a few hours of no internet connectivity, this is going to crash with a stack overflow. Recursion is a bad way to implement retry functionality even if you fix the bug you're asking about - it's better to use a loop.

Comment: This: `except Exceptione:` does not define `e` though your `print()` call expects it to contain the exception object. Did you maybe mean `except Exception as e`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the function recursevly

```
  def get_position(self) -> position.Position:
      while True:
          result = position.Position()
          try:
              return result.json_parse(self.client.futures_position_information(symbol=SYMBOl))
          except Exceptione:
              print(f'err: GET_POSITION {e}')
              time.sleep(5)
```